# Get fields from metabox array

Tags: custom-field, functions, metabox

In my functions I'm registering multiple metaboxes with custom fields. A single metabox array for instance, looks like this:

In functions.php

```
$meta_boxes[] = array(
    'id' => 'general_info',
    'title' => 'General Information',
    'pages' => array('post', 'page', 'link'), // multiple post types, accept custom post types
    'context' => 'normal', // normal, advanced, side (optional)
    'priority' => 'high', // high, low (optional)
    'fields' => array(
        array(
            'name' => 'Asking Price',
            'id' => $prefix . 'asking_price',
            'type' => 'text',
            'std' => ''
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'Currency',
            'id' => $prefix . 'currency',
            'type' => 'text',
            'std' => 'USD'
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'Salesman',
            'id' => $prefix . 'salesman',
            'type' => 'text',
            'std' => 'Your Name'
        )
    )
);
```

In my theme, how can get all the field names (and even values if possible) from metabox `general_info` ? I'm trying to retrieve data from each metabox separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `get_post_custom`, it will return an array of all the posts meta info.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_custom

Comment: Thanks but I need post meta for metabox named "general_info" only. I have many metaboxes

Comment: Then use `get_post_meta` with the key being "general_info".

Comment: that will give me the key for the meta value not all the fields in the array. I'm having trouble finding a solution for this. Maybe I'm not explaining right

Answer (score 0):

you have to return metabox. 
place the below code at the end

`return $metaboxes`;

This will solve your problem

Comment: And why would this work? Please explain your suggestion. And BTW, it's `$meta_boxes`.

Comment: We need to return an array to retrieve data from metabox, which u saved as an array.